# powershell exporting random password and usernames

Tags: powershell

I have been resetting user's password via like below.My question is : how can I get output like below?

Desired output:

```
username,password
user01,Wkyqnm7l
user02,Wfyqrm8l
```

script:

```
import-Csv c:\tmp\users.csv  | `
    ForEach-Object { 
    $filenamedate = "C:\tmp\{0}.txt" -f (get-date -f 'MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss')

$PassWord = -join ([char[]]"!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" |Get-Random -Count 8)
$Password | Export-csv -Path $fileNameDate -NoTypeInformation

$SecPW = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PassWord -AsPlainText -Force

    
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $_.dn -Reset -NewPassword $SecPW }
```

Comment: Does the csv file contain the user samaccountname aswell?

Comment: hi theo , already added the user samaccountname   inside `$_.dn`  variable

Comment: So the `dn` value is not actually the DN?

Comment: not DN,  already added the user samaccountname inside $_.dn variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column`dn` in your csv is actually the user `SamAccountName` instead of the `DistinguishedName`, you could use

```
$filenamedate = "C:\tmp\{0}.csv" -f (get-date -f 'MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss')
$result = Import-Csv c:\tmp\users.csv  |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $PassWord = -join ([char[]]"!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | Get-Random -Count 8)
        $SecPW = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PassWord -AsPlainText -Force
        Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $_.dn -Reset -NewPassword $SecPW
        
        # output an object
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            username = $_.dn
            password = $PassWord
        }
    }

$result | Export-Csv -Path $fileNameDate -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This is faster / better than my example. Less Disk I/O = faster execution.

Comment: @Theo I have a question. have you had a chance take a look ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931125/powershell-azure-licence-based-on-ad-group

Answer (score 0):

If DN is actually the DistinguishedName you can do something like `($_.DN).Split(',')[0] -replace 'CN='` to get the sAMAccountName.

If you want one file per user then `$fileNameDate` should be inside the loop but you'll also need a variable to identify the files.

```
$charMap=[char[]]"!@#$%^&*0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
$filenamedate = "C:\tmp\{0}.csv" -f (get-date -f 'MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss')

import-Csv c:\tmp\users.csv | ForEach-Object {     
    $PassWord = -join ($charMap |Get-Random -Count 8)
    $SecPW = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PassWord -AsPlainText -Force
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $_.dn -Reset -NewPassword $SecPW 
    
    [pscustomobject]@{
        UserName=$_.DN # if the DN is actually the samAccountName
        Password=$Password
    } | Export-Csv $fileNameDate -NoTypeInformation -Append 
}
```