# Granting send as or send as behalf permissions to multiple users?

Tags: powershell

I want to grant both send as and/ or send as behalf permissions multiple users at the same time.
Now , I am able to grant permission one-by-one via below script.

My CSV file :

```
"DisplayName","PrimarySMTPAddress","SendAsPermissions","SendOnBehalfPermissions"
"DG01","DG01@contoso.com","CONTOSO\Ituser01;CONTOSO\Ituser02;CONTOSO\Ituser03","user01@contoso.com;user02@contoso.com"
"DG02","DG02@contoso.com","","user11@contoso.com;user42@contoso.com"
"DG03","DG03@contoso.com","CONTOSO\Ituser34",""
```

Script :

```
$importDLs = Import-Csv -Path C:\TEMP\delegate.csv

foreach ($importDL in $importDLs){

$importDL.SendAsPermissions
$importDL.SendOnBehalfPermissions


#Grant a user Send-On-Behalf to a distribution group so they can Send-on-behalf of the distribution group.
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity "$importDL.PrimarySMTPAddress" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{add="$importDL.SendOnBehalfPermissions"}

#Grant a user Send As permissions to a distribution group so they can send as the distribution group
Get-DistributionGroup "$importDL.PrimarySMTPAddress" | Add-ADPermission -User "$importDL.SendAsPermissions" -ExtendedRights "Send As"


}
```

LAST UPDATE :

```
$importDLs = Import-Csv -Path C:\TEMP\delegate.csv

foreach ($importDL in $importDLs){

$importDLSendAs2 = $importDL.SendAsPermissions -split ";"
$importDLSendAsBehalf2 = $importDL.SendOnBehalfPermissions -split ";"
$dgmail=$importDL.PrimarySMTPAddress


foreach ($importDLSendAs in $importDLSendAs2) {
$domain,$importDLSendAsUser = $importDLSendAs.split('\')
$importDLSendAsUser

#Grant a user Send As permissions to a distribution group so they can send as the distribution group
Get-DistributionGroup "$dgmail" | Add-ADPermission -User "$importDLSendAsUser" -ExtendedRights "Send As"


}

foreach ($importDLSendAsBehalf in $importDLSendAsBehalf2) {

#Grant a user Send-On-Behalf to a distribution group so they can Send-on-behalf of the distribution group.
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity "$dgmail" -GrantSendOnBehalfTo @{add="$importDLSendAsBehalf"}


}



}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to grant both send as and/ or send as behalf permissions multiple users at the same time.
Now , I am able to grant permission one-by-one via my script.

Comment: Re `Set-DistributionGroup`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps states "To add or remove one or more values without affecting any existing entries, use the following syntax: `@{Add="Value1","Value2"...; Remove="Value3","Value4"...}`."

Comment: Re `Add-ADPermisson`:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-adpermission?view=exchange-ps suggests that the `-User` parameter only accepts a single value (and doesn't accept pipeline input).

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with your edited code? I think you need to change the syntax for the `-GrantSendOnBehalfTo` parameter to either `@{Add=[string[]]$importDLSendAsBehalf2}` and remove the `foreach ($importDLSendAsBehalf in $importDLSendAsBehalf2) {..}` loop, or create a comma-separated string of quoted email addresses from that like `@{Add=(($importDLSendAsBehalf2 | ForEach-Object { '"{0}"' -f $_ }) -join ',')}`. Can you try?

Comment: my script runs. but , Due to that, I have large environment. it runs slowly. how can I tune my script ?

Comment: is there any comment ?

Comment: The only thing that can speed up a little is that you can add multiple email addresses on the `GrantSendOnBehalfTo` parameter as I have already commented. That will save you the final loop